# Pandas df manipulation: new column with list of values if other column rows repeated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a df like this:

```
ID   Cluster Product 
 1         4     'b'  
 1         4     'f'
 1         4     'w'
 2         7     'u'
 2         7     'b'
 3         5     'h'
 3         5     'f'
 3         5     'm'
 3         5     'd'
 4         7     's'
 4         7     'b'
 4         7     'g'
```

Where ID is the primary and unique key of another df that is the source for this df. Cluster is not a key, different IDs often have same Cluster value; anyway it's an information I have to carry on.

What I want to obtain is this dataframe:

```
ID   Cluster    Product_List_by_ID 
 1         4     ['b','f','w'] 
 2         7     ['u','b']
 3         5     ['h','f','m','d']
 4         7     ['s','b','g']
```

If this is not possible, also a dictionary like this could be fine:

```
d = {ID:[1,2,3,4], Cluster:[4,7,5,7], 
     Product_List_by_ID:[['b','f','w'],['u','b'],['h','f','m','d'],['s','b','g']]}
```

I have tried many ways unsuccessfully.. it seems that it is not possible to insert lists as pandas dataframe values.. 
Anyway I think it should not be so difficult to get the goal in some tricky way.. Sorry if I am going out of mind, but I am new to coding

Any suggests?! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Cluster']).Product.apply(list)

ID  Cluster
1   4               ['b', 'f', 'w']
2   7                    ['u', 'b']
3   5          ['h', 'f', 'm', 'd']
4   7               ['s', 'b', 'g']
Name: Product, dtype: object
```

Comment: What all operations can we do after groupby. Any good resource for that?

Comment: [`groupby` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi thx... commenting is difficult for me :-)

Comment: Great! I had not thought to the ".apply(list)". Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Have a look to my edits.. I've noticed that len of "groupby series" is 17645, while there are 17668 different IDs.. I am sure about those numbers, may the groupby has deleted something or I have to check better my stuff?! Thanks

Comment: @piRSquared thanks very much for this, is there a way to duplicate but not drop? as in keep columns 'Cluster' and 'ID' untouched, but create a new column with list of duplicated rows repeated?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is first remove `'` from column `Product` if necessary by [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.Product = df.Product.str.strip("'")
```

And then `groupby` with `apply`, last if need `dictionary` use [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `orient='list'`

```
print (df.groupby(['ID', 'Cluster'])
         .Product.apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
         .reset_index()
         .to_dict(orient='list'))

{'Cluster': [4, 7, 5, 7], 
'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
'Product': [['b', 'f', 'w'], ['u', 'b'], 
            ['h', 'f', 'm', 'd'], ['s', 'b', 'g']]}
```

Comment: Very fine: now also the second way i wondered is explained! Anyway I can't find out why len of this dict[keys] is 17645 while df has 17668 different IDs..

Comment: Yes, I think about it now. Are data confidental? How do you test their length?

Comment: You can check length by `print (len(df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Cluster']).index))` - remove duplicates by first and second column and then check length of index.

Comment: Ok, data are confidential, I have just run your print removing duplicates: result = 17645; while with df['ID'].unique() i get that there are 17668 different IDs..

Comment: I see problem. You check it wrong way. Because you need unique of both columns together, not only one column `ID`.

Comment: Because in your sample is same position of values in both columns, but in real data not.

Comment: You can test it with this sample: `np.random.seed(100)`
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(20,3)), columns=['ID', 'Cluster', 'Product'])`
`print (df)`

`print (len(df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Cluster']).index))`

`print (df.ID.nunique())`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same.. now I have checked unique by both columns, result = 17645. Evidently ID was not a "real" ID ;)  Thanks!

Comment: Thx for helping OP figure this out :-)

Comment: I thanks too for all helping comments.